# How do I ignore an [XMLIgnore] Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-3.5, xml-serialization

I'm trying to serialize some objects obtained from a 3rd Party .NET Lib to an XML File.

When I `Go To Definition` for the object, some of the Properties of that object are marked as `[XMLIgnore]`

Is there any way to tell my `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` to ignore the fact that some properties have that attribute and that it should serialize everything in the object.

I could probably obtain the source and recompile it without the `XMLIgnore` attributes but it'd be nice if `XmlSerializer` had some nice override property like

```
XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(
   typeof(MyObject),
   Settings.DoNotApplyXMLAttributeRules
);
```

Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT**

Have tried the XmlAttributeOverrides as suggested but not having much joy.
Here's the object definition (it's from the FlickrAPI for a Photo)

```
[Serializable]
public class Photo
{
    //Some code omitted
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string LargeUrl { get; }

}
```

And heres the serializer code I've written... still doesn't work...

```
XmlWriter xtw = XmlWriter.Create( Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Data.xml") );

XmlAttributes photoAttributes = new XmlAttributes();
photoAttributes.XmlIgnore = false;

XmlAttributeOverrides photoOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
photoOverrides.Add(typeof(Photo), "LargeUrl", photoAttributes);

XmlSerializer xmlphoto = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Photo), photoOverrides);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use:

```
XmlAttributeOverrides
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore.aspx

Edit: (Following the question EDIT)

the property must be public and have a getter and setter to be serialized.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28VS.85%29.aspx

((see first Note))

Comment: Have tried that but no joy. Any other suggestions would be appreciated. I've added the code to the original question in case I'm doing something silly.

Comment: LargeUrl does not have a setter, so even without the XmlIgnore attribute, it won't be serialized.

Comment: ah right. I've gotten around it by creating a proxy class to store the values in and then serializing that seperately.